# even after i do git add . for all the files, but still this one file / folder doesnt get tracked,

Tags: github

this is the result of git diff.

diff --git a/sserver b/sserver
--- a/sserver
+++ b/sserver
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit f15774db7a5a9891e282745e3401344d5d45f449
+Subproject commit f15774db7a5a9891e282745e3401344d5d45f449-dirty

Answer (score 0):

The culprit of this may be the .gitignore file. Open the ".gitignore" file and see if the folder is purposely being omitted.